# input must be under 256 bytes, when try encrypt AES SecretKey?

Tags: android, aes, rsa

I found a solution to encrypt large amounts of data using RSA.

1. Generate a symmetric key
2. Encrypt data with a symmetric key
3. encrypt the symmetric key with rsa
4. Send encrypted key and data
5. decrypt encrypted symmetric key using rsa
6. decrypt data with a symmetric key

But when I try to encrypt AES key, error

```
private val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
    private val decrCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
    private val simmetrycCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
    private val simmetrycDecodeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
    private val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
        .apply { initialize(2048) }
    private val simmetrycGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").apply {
        init(256)
    }
 val pair = generator.genKeyPair()
 Store.myPublicKey = pair.public
 Store.myPrivateKey = pair.private
Store.myPublicEncoded = Store.myPublicKey.encoded
 Store.simmetrycMyKey = simmetrycGenerator.generateKey()
 Store.simmetrycKeyEncoded = Store.simmetrycMyKey.encoded
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, serverKey)
decrCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Store.myPrivateKey)
simmetrycCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Store.simmetrycMyKey)
simmetrycDecodeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Store.simmetrycMyKey)
ase64.encode(cipher.doFinal(Store.myPublicEncoded), Base64.NO_WRAP).decodeToString()

//exception: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: input must be under 256 bytes
```

Comment: What you describe is standard RSA/AES hybrid encryption. Why do you try to encrypt the public RSA public key by it's privet key? That is what you in the last line of your posted code, but that is not of the hybrid encryption scheme.

Comment: Yes, thank you) It's all my inattention.

Comment: But that will never work. The RSA public key is always larger than the maximum size you can encrypt using it's matching private key.